# SSIS & WMI Event Watcher & Data Flow Task

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I've got a WMI Event Watcher in my SSIS package which successfully watches a folder for a file. (i.e. in debug mode, it turns green when I copy the file into the watched folder.)

I've added a a data flow task to import this (excel) file into a SQL database.

Trouble is the data flow task never fires.

So,

(a) am I using the correct 'tasks' to create import my data and if so...

(b) any thoughts on why the data flow task does not import.

Thanks in advance,

Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without looking at the package myself I would check to make sure that the line coming out of the script task is the Success line (Green).

I would also check into [File Watcher Task](http://www.sqlis.com/post/file-watcher-task.aspx).  I don't know enough (actually anything) about WMI...but I've used the File Watcher Task in my last two projects with excellent results.